# Angular JS - Cancel button on form suppress form submission

Tags: angularjs

Consider a form with three buttons:

```
<form ng-submit="updateUser()">
  <div>Name <input type="text" ng-model="userToEdit.name" /></div>
  <div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="updateUser()">Save</button>
    <button class="btn" ng-click="cancelEdit()">Cancel</button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="deleteUser(userToEdit)"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Delete</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

When I click cancel, cancelEdit() is being called, then updateUser() is being called.  I don't want the updateUser() method to be called.  Is there a way to suppress this form submission (preferebly wtihout jQuery?)

Note: I'd still like to be able to hit enter and default to the Save action.

Comment: Can you try to define a button with the type="submit" and see if the submission is only triggered when that button is clicked?

Comment: I removed ng-submit and added type="submit" to the Save button, and pressing enter while focused on the text box did not submit my form.

Comment: If you specify type="submit" on a button you must have the ng-submit directive on your form and you do not need the ng-click on the submit button.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

There is a `type` attribute for the `<button>` which defaults to **submit** - see [this spec](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/button). Thus every button in your form is a **submit** button. You need to specify the **button** type for buttons which should not trigger the form submission, like this:

```
<form ng-submit="updateUser()">
  <div>Name <input type="text" ng-model="userToEdit.name" /></div>
  <div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" ng-click="cancelEdit()">Cancel</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="deleteUser(userToEdit)"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Delete</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

And also no need to put the submit action to both `ng-click` and `ng-submit` - it will trigger double submit. I would advise to use `ng-submit` because it catches all ways of form submission, like pressing ENTER and not only clicking on submit button.

Comment: This is the best answer !

Comment: You are spot on with this line: `There is a type attribute for the <button> which defaults to submit` Adding `type="button"` was the perfect solution. Thanks for that!

Comment: `type="reset"` is probably the best type for a `<button>` to clear the form

Answer (score 13):

Try this

```
<form ng-submit="updateUser()">
  <div>Name <input type="text" ng-model="userToEdit.name" /></div>
  <div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    <a class="btn" ng-click="cancelEdit()">Cancel</a>
    <a class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="deleteUser(userToEdit)"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Delete</a>
  </div>
</form>
```

or this

```
<form>
  <div>Name <input type="text" ng-model="userToEdit.name" /></div>
  <div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="updateUser()">Save</button>
    <button class="btn" ng-click="cancelEdit()">Cancel</button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="deleteUser(userToEdit)"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Delete</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

ultimately I don't think you need `updateUser()` twice in the html

Comment: Thanks, this works (I'll accept once SO lets me).  The first solution lets me press enter while on the text area, so it's the one I prefer.

Comment: See Shimon Rachlenko's answer for a way to keep using `<button>` tags for the Cancel behavior with the form's `ng-submit` directive.

Answer (score 6):

You can use for cancel button type="reset":

```
<button type="reset" class="btn" ng-click="cancelEdit()">Cancel</button>
```

> The button is a reset button (resets the form-data to its initial values)

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_type.asp

Comment: this resets it back to blank, not back to what it originally was

Comment: This is not resetting at all,

Comment: This doesn't work because it erases all the form data so that the next time you load form to edit the information all the fields are empty. Better to use `type="button"` solution instead.

Answer (score 1):

I was having same problem.I used anchor instead of button.

```
<form ng-submit="updateUser()">
  <div>Name <input type="text" ng-model="userToEdit.name" /></div>
  <div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="updateUser()">Save</button>
<a class="btn btn-danger"  ng-click="cancelEdit()" role="button">Cancel</a>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="deleteUser(userToEdit)"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Delete</button>

  </div>
</form>
```